# 32 ft usb 3 cable power not suficient

Tags: usb, ipad, cabling

I am trying to power an ipad using a 32 ft active usb cable as seen [here](https://www.monoprice.com/Product?p_id=6149&gclid=Cj0KEQiAot_FBRCqt8jVsoDKoZABEiQAqFL76DIlNfpCxNWAQnWWhAv1iF0x5s8W57PbwIkILwH1JCgaAoef8P8HAQ). The issue is the power at the end of the run just isn't sufficient to keep the ipad charging (4.7v). I have done some research but have come up empty. most recommendations involve adding a powered hub near the end of the pull however this is not possible in my situation. How would I extend the life of the power over usb up to 32 feet or boost it at the main? to reiterate this is a power question i need a way to increase the output of power enough so that the ipad will charge. I am not concerned about data transference.

Comment: The extension cable is using part of the USB's power to boost the USB data signals, causing less power to be available to the device.

Comment: As far as I can tell, none of the answers to the proposed duplicate address the OP's intent to boost the *power output* over the USB cable run.

Comment: You need to use usb over cat5.

Comment: The proposed duplicate focuses on normal use of a USB connection (move data).  That doesn't really address this question, which focuses on just power.  The answers here are relevant to this question.  The answers on the other aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get better performance out of a physically thicker USB cable.  DC electrical current  is resisted more by thin conductors, which is OK on a 6-foot desktop cable, but becomes a problem on a 32-foot cable across the room.
You've mentioned that it's not an option, but a good solution is just a regular 32-foot power cable, transformer, and little USB hub to provide power to the iPad.  Put it all inside a shroud with a glue gun, and screw the shroud to the bottom of the desk or counter.
"USB Extender" solutions usually need power at the far end.

Comment: You beat me to it. Actually, you don't even need the hub, just a power brick with a USB power connector, like the iPad's own charger.  With any form of USB tether, you're paying for the ability to move data over that distance.

Comment: I think im going to do that. Just run a long power cable in the wall to a short usb charger cable.

Answer (score 2):

It would be more efficient, & no more unsightly, to just run a mains extension the 32ft then plug in your regular charger, if data is not a concern.

Comment: That is how it is currently configured. USB straight to 2 prong outlet.